# Why to fix "Frameworks/Flutter.framework: Permission denied" while building iOS native app with flutter module?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

I created an iOS single view app (hostapp) and converted it to pod workspace. Runs well.
Then created flutter module (clientapp), provided iOS team. Runs well, independently.
Turned off Bitcode for hostapp and clientapp, as it caused other problems.
Now added clientapp to hostapp via podfile, no internal code changes. After pod install in hostapp, I tried building it. Then it throws `/Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: Permission denied`

- Both hostapp and clientapp are default iOS and flutter app. No changes whatsoever.
- I followed this official guide https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps.
- Have tried to search for similar issue but no success there.
- Tested on Xcode 10 and 11
- Tried legacy build
- Tried Xcode 11, 10, 9.3-compatible, etc
- Changed flutter chmod to 777
- Changed `/Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.app/Frameworks/` chmod to 777

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/hostapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.build/Script-4899A4A5D85C0D737A68EFD6.sh (in target 'hostapp' from project 'hostapp')
    cd /Users/iVoIP/projects/xcode/hostapp
    /bin/sh -c /Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/hostapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.build/Script-4899A4A5D85C0D737A68EFD6.sh

mkdir -p /Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/iVoIP/projects/xcode/hostapp/Pods/../../clientapp/.ios/Flutter/engine/Flutter.framework" "/Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
Flutter.framework/
Flutter.framework/Flutter
Flutter.framework/Info.plist
Flutter.framework/icudtl.dat
Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/
Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources

sent 94440038 bytes  received 120 bytes  188880316.00 bytes/sec
total size is 94428117  speedup is 1.00
Stripped /Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter of architectures: armv7 arm64
Code Signing /Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework with Identity -
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
/Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: replacing existing signature
/Users/iVoIP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hostapp-czxdwjjefjvrnhhdvbmaqeczngbh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hostapp.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: Permission denied
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 1):

Locate `xcode_backend.sh` file in the Flutter folder at this path `‎⁨flutter/packages⁩/flutter_tools/⁨bin`⁩ and at line 140 change it to

```
    RunCommand find "${derived_dir}/engine/Flutter.framework" -type f -iname '.h' -exec chmod a-w "{}" \;
```

This will do it !!

Comment: Changed as you said, but still same. Do I need to recreate the project or any additional things?

Comment: after changing that line, delete the derivedData and clean the xcode project... check once! If that doesn't work, post the xcode_backend.sh file contents and flutter doctor command output also !

Comment: Thanks for the help. Moving to master branch solved the issue. [git issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41277)

Comment: Thank you!! saved my day man!
In my case, this line was already there but it still didn't worked with flutter_blue. I've changed it to xxx instead a-w and it worked

Answer (score 0):

See this issues:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40146

```sh
--- a/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh
+++ b/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh
@@ -141,7 +141,7 @@ BuildApp() {
     mkdir "${derived_dir}/engine"
     RunCommand cp -r -- "${flutter_podspec}" "${derived_dir}/engine"
     RunCommand cp -r -- "${flutter_framework}" "${derived_dir}/engine"
-    RunCommand find "${derived_dir}/engine/Flutter.framework" -type f -exec chmod a-w "{}" \;
+    RunCommand find "${derived_dir}/engine/Flutter.framework" -type f -iname '.h' -exec chmod a-w "{}" \;
   else
     RunCommand rm -rf -- "${derived_dir}/Flutter.framework"
     RunCommand cp -r -- "${flutter_framework}" "${derived_dir}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Flutter latest to solve this problem.

If you cannot upgrade because of x reason, open up Flutter SDK's `packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh` and replace with below code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright 2016 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file.

RunCommand() {
  if [[ -n "$VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING" ]]; then
    echo "♦ $*"
  fi
  "$@"
  return $?
}

# When provided with a pipe by the host Flutter build process, output to the
# pipe goes to stdout of the Flutter build process directly.
StreamOutput() {
  if [[ -n "$SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE" ]]; then
    echo "$1" > $SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE
  fi
}

EchoError() {
  echo "$@" 1>&2
}

AssertExists() {
  if [[ ! -e "$1" ]]; then
    if [[ -h "$1" ]]; then
      EchoError "The path $1 is a symlink to a path that does not exist"
    else
      EchoError "The path $1 does not exist"
    fi
    exit -1
  fi
  return 0
}

BuildApp() {
  local project_path="${SOURCE_ROOT}/.."
  if [[ -n "$FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH" ]]; then
    project_path="${FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH}"
  fi

  local target_path="lib/main.dart"
  if [[ -n "$FLUTTER_TARGET" ]]; then
    target_path="${FLUTTER_TARGET}"
  fi

  local derived_dir="${SOURCE_ROOT}/Flutter"
  if [[ -e "${project_path}/.ios" ]]; then
    derived_dir="${project_path}/.ios/Flutter"
  fi

  # Default value of assets_path is flutter_assets
  local assets_path="flutter_assets"
  # The value of assets_path can set by add FLTAssetsPath to AppFrameworkInfo.plist
  FLTAssetsPath=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :FLTAssetsPath" "${derived_dir}/AppFrameworkInfo.plist" 2>/dev/null)
  if [[ -n "$FLTAssetsPath" ]]; then
    assets_path="${FLTAssetsPath}"
  fi

  # Use FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE if it's set, otherwise use the Xcode build configuration name
  # This means that if someone wants to use an Xcode build config other than Debug/Profile/Release,
  # they _must_ set FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE so we know what type of artifact to build.
  local build_mode="$(echo "${FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE:-${CONFIGURATION}}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")"
  local artifact_variant="unknown"
  case "$build_mode" in
    *release*) build_mode="release"; artifact_variant="ios-release";;
    *profile*) build_mode="profile"; artifact_variant="ios-profile";;
    *debug*) build_mode="debug"; artifact_variant="ios";;
    *)
      EchoError "========================================================================"
      EchoError "ERROR: Unknown FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE: ${build_mode}."
      EchoError "Valid values are 'Debug', 'Profile', or 'Release' (case insensitive)."
      EchoError "This is controlled by the FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE environment variable."
      EchoError "If that is not set, the CONFIGURATION environment variable is used."
      EchoError ""
      EchoError "You can fix this by either adding an appropriately named build"
      EchoError "configuration, or adding an appropriate value for FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE to the"
      EchoError ".xcconfig file for the current build configuration (${CONFIGURATION})."
      EchoError "========================================================================"
      exit -1;;
  esac

  # Archive builds (ACTION=install) should always run in release mode.
  if [[ "$ACTION" == "install" && "$build_mode" != "release" ]]; then
    EchoError "========================================================================"
    EchoError "ERROR: Flutter archive builds must be run in Release mode."
    EchoError ""
    EchoError "To correct, ensure FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE is set to release or run:"
    EchoError "flutter build ios --release"
    EchoError ""
    EchoError "then re-run Archive from Xcode."
    EchoError "========================================================================"
    exit -1
  fi

  local framework_path="${FLUTTER_ROOT}/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/${artifact_variant}"

  AssertExists "${framework_path}"
  AssertExists "${project_path}"

  RunCommand mkdir -p -- "$derived_dir"
  AssertExists "$derived_dir"

  RunCommand rm -rf -- "${derived_dir}/App.framework"

  local flutter_engine_flag=""
  local local_engine_flag=""
  local flutter_framework="${framework_path}/Flutter.framework"
  local flutter_podspec="${framework_path}/Flutter.podspec"

  if [[ -n "$FLUTTER_ENGINE" ]]; then
    flutter_engine_flag="--local-engine-src-path=${FLUTTER_ENGINE}"
  fi

  if [[ -n "$LOCAL_ENGINE" ]]; then
    if [[ $(echo "$LOCAL_ENGINE" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]") != *"$build_mode"* ]]; then
      EchoError "========================================================================"
      EchoError "ERROR: Requested build with Flutter local engine at '${LOCAL_ENGINE}'"
      EchoError "This engine is not compatible with FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE: '${build_mode}'."
      EchoError "You can fix this by updating the LOCAL_ENGINE environment variable, or"
      EchoError "by running:"
      EchoError "  flutter build ios --local-engine=ios_${build_mode}"
      EchoError "or"
      EchoError "  flutter build ios --local-engine=ios_${build_mode}_unopt"
      EchoError "========================================================================"
      exit -1
    fi
    local_engine_flag="--local-engine=${LOCAL_ENGINE}"
    flutter_framework="${FLUTTER_ENGINE}/out/${LOCAL_ENGINE}/Flutter.framework"
    flutter_podspec="${FLUTTER_ENGINE}/out/${LOCAL_ENGINE}/Flutter.podspec"
  fi

  local bitcode_flag=""
  if [[ $ENABLE_BITCODE == "YES" ]]; then
    bitcode_flag="--bitcode"
  fi

  if [[ -e "${project_path}/.ios" ]]; then
    RunCommand rm -rf -- "${derived_dir}/engine"
    mkdir "${derived_dir}/engine"
    RunCommand cp -r -- "${flutter_podspec}" "${derived_dir}/engine"
    RunCommand cp -r -- "${flutter_framework}" "${derived_dir}/engine"
  else
    RunCommand rm -rf -- "${derived_dir}/Flutter.framework"
    RunCommand cp -- "${flutter_podspec}" "${derived_dir}"
    RunCommand cp -r -- "${flutter_framework}" "${derived_dir}"
  fi

  RunCommand pushd "${project_path}" > /dev/null

  AssertExists "${target_path}"

  local verbose_flag=""
  if [[ -n "$VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING" ]]; then
    verbose_flag="--verbose"
  fi

  local build_dir="${FLUTTER_BUILD_DIR:-build}"

  local track_widget_creation_flag=""
  if [[ -n "$TRACK_WIDGET_CREATION" ]]; then
    track_widget_creation_flag="--track-widget-creation"
  fi

  if [[ "${build_mode}" != "debug" ]]; then
    StreamOutput " ├─Building Dart code..."
    # Transform ARCHS to comma-separated list of target architectures.
    local archs="${ARCHS// /,}"
    if [[ $archs =~ .*i386.* || $archs =~ .*x86_64.* ]]; then
      EchoError "========================================================================"
      EchoError "ERROR: Flutter does not support running in profile or release mode on"
      EchoError "the Simulator (this build was: '$build_mode')."
      EchoError "You can ensure Flutter runs in Debug mode with your host app in release"
      EchoError "mode by setting FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE=debug in the .xcconfig associated"
      EchoError "with the ${CONFIGURATION} build configuration."
      EchoError "========================================================================"
      exit -1
    fi

    RunCommand "${FLUTTER_ROOT}/bin/flutter" --suppress-analytics           \
      ${verbose_flag}                                                       \
      build aot                                                             \
      --output-dir="${build_dir}/aot"                                       \
      --target-platform=ios                                                 \
      --target="${target_path}"                                             \
      --${build_mode}                                                       \
      --ios-arch="${archs}"                                                 \
      ${flutter_engine_flag}                                                \
      ${local_engine_flag}                                                  \
      ${bitcode_flag}

    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
      EchoError "Failed to build ${project_path}."
      exit -1
    fi
    StreamOutput "done"

    local app_framework="${build_dir}/aot/App.framework"

    RunCommand cp -r -- "${app_framework}" "${derived_dir}"

    if [[ "${build_mode}" == "release" ]]; then
      StreamOutput " ├─Generating dSYM file..."
      # Xcode calls `symbols` during app store upload, which uses Spotlight to
      # find dSYM files for embedded frameworks. When it finds the dSYM file for
      # `App.framework` it throws an error, which aborts the app store upload.
      # To avoid this, we place the dSYM files in a folder ending with ".noindex",
      # which hides it from Spotlight, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22560.
      RunCommand mkdir -p -- "${build_dir}/dSYMs.noindex"
      RunCommand xcrun dsymutil -o "${build_dir}/dSYMs.noindex/App.framework.dSYM" "${app_framework}/App"
      if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        EchoError "Failed to generate debug symbols (dSYM) file for ${app_framework}/App."
        exit -1
      fi
      StreamOutput "done"

      StreamOutput " ├─Stripping debug symbols..."
      RunCommand xcrun strip -x -S "${derived_dir}/App.framework/App"
      if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        EchoError "Failed to strip ${derived_dir}/App.framework/App."
        exit -1
      fi
      StreamOutput "done"
    fi

  else
    RunCommand mkdir -p -- "${derived_dir}/App.framework"

    # Build stub for all requested architectures.
    local arch_flags=""
    read -r -a archs <<< "$ARCHS"
    for arch in "${archs[@]}"; do
      arch_flags="${arch_flags}-arch $arch "
    done

    RunCommand eval "$(echo "static const int Moo = 88;" | xcrun clang -x c \
        ${arch_flags} \
        -fembed-bitcode-marker \
        -dynamiclib \
        -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker '@executable_path/Frameworks' \
        -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker '@loader_path/Frameworks' \
        -install_name '@rpath/App.framework/App' \
        -o "${derived_dir}/App.framework/App" -)"
  fi

  local plistPath="${project_path}/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist"
  if [[ -e "${project_path}/.ios" ]]; then
    plistPath="${project_path}/.ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist"
  fi

  RunCommand cp -- "$plistPath" "${derived_dir}/App.framework/Info.plist"

  local precompilation_flag=""
  if [[ "$CURRENT_ARCH" != "x86_64" ]] && [[ "$build_mode" != "debug" ]]; then
    precompilation_flag="--precompiled"
  fi

  StreamOutput " ├─Assembling Flutter resources..."
  RunCommand "${FLUTTER_ROOT}/bin/flutter"     \
    ${verbose_flag}                                                         \
    build bundle                                                            \
    --target-platform=ios                                                   \
    --target="${target_path}"                                               \
    --${build_mode}                                                         \
    --depfile="${build_dir}/snapshot_blob.bin.d"                            \
    --asset-dir="${derived_dir}/App.framework/${assets_path}"               \
    ${precompilation_flag}                                                  \
    ${flutter_engine_flag}                                                  \
    ${local_engine_flag}                                                    \
    ${track_widget_creation_flag}

  if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    EchoError "Failed to package ${project_path}."
    exit -1
  fi
  StreamOutput "done"
  StreamOutput " └─Compiling, linking and signing..."

  RunCommand popd > /dev/null

  echo "Project ${project_path} built and packaged successfully."
  return 0
}

# Returns the CFBundleExecutable for the specified framework directory.
GetFrameworkExecutablePath() {
  local framework_dir="$1"

  local plist_path="${framework_dir}/Info.plist"
  local executable="$(defaults read "${plist_path}" CFBundleExecutable)"
  echo "${framework_dir}/${executable}"
}

# Destructively thins the specified executable file to include only the
# specified architectures.
LipoExecutable() {
  local executable="$1"
  shift
  # Split $@ into an array.
  read -r -a archs <<< "$@"

  # Extract architecture-specific framework executables.
  local all_executables=()
  for arch in "${archs[@]}"; do
    local output="${executable}_${arch}"
    local lipo_info="$(lipo -info "${executable}")"
    if [[ "${lipo_info}" == "Non-fat file:"* ]]; then
      if [[ "${lipo_info}" != *"${arch}" ]]; then
        echo "Non-fat binary ${executable} is not ${arch}. Running lipo -info:"
        echo "${lipo_info}"
        exit 1
      fi
    else
      lipo -output "${output}" -extract "${arch}" "${executable}"
      if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        all_executables+=("${output}")
      else
        echo "Failed to extract ${arch} for ${executable}. Running lipo -info:"
        lipo -info "${executable}"
        exit 1
      fi
    fi
  done

  # Generate a merged binary from the architecture-specific executables.
  # Skip this step for non-fat executables.
  if [[ ${#all_executables[@]} > 0 ]]; then
    local merged="${executable}_merged"
    lipo -output "${merged}" -create "${all_executables[@]}"

    cp -f -- "${merged}" "${executable}" > /dev/null
    rm -f -- "${merged}" "${all_executables[@]}"
  fi
}

# Destructively thins the specified framework to include only the specified
# architectures.
ThinFramework() {
  local framework_dir="$1"
  shift

  local plist_path="${framework_dir}/Info.plist"
  local executable="$(GetFrameworkExecutablePath "${framework_dir}")"
  LipoExecutable "${executable}" "$@"
}

ThinAppFrameworks() {
  local app_path="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"
  local frameworks_dir="${app_path}/Frameworks"

  [[ -d "$frameworks_dir" ]] || return 0
  find "${app_path}" -type d -name "*.framework" | while read framework_dir; do
    ThinFramework "$framework_dir" "$ARCHS"
  done
}

# Adds the App.framework as an embedded binary and the flutter_assets as
# resources.
EmbedFlutterFrameworks() {
  AssertExists "${FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH}"

  # Prefer the hidden .ios folder, but fallback to a visible ios folder if .ios
  # doesn't exist.
  local flutter_ios_out_folder="${FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH}/.ios/Flutter"
  local flutter_ios_engine_folder="${FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH}/.ios/Flutter/engine"
  if [[ ! -d ${flutter_ios_out_folder} ]]; then
    flutter_ios_out_folder="${FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH}/ios/Flutter"
    flutter_ios_engine_folder="${FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH}/ios/Flutter"
  fi

  AssertExists "${flutter_ios_out_folder}"

  # Embed App.framework from Flutter into the app (after creating the Frameworks directory
  # if it doesn't already exist).
  local xcode_frameworks_dir=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}"/"${PRODUCT_NAME}".app/Frameworks"
  RunCommand mkdir -p -- "${xcode_frameworks_dir}"
  RunCommand cp -Rv -- "${flutter_ios_out_folder}/App.framework" "${xcode_frameworks_dir}"

  # Embed the actual Flutter.framework that the Flutter app expects to run against,
  # which could be a local build or an arch/type specific build.
  # Remove it first since Xcode might be trying to hold some of these files - this way we're
  # sure to get a clean copy.
  RunCommand rm -rf -- "${xcode_frameworks_dir}/Flutter.framework"
  RunCommand cp -Rv -- "${flutter_ios_engine_folder}/Flutter.framework" "${xcode_frameworks_dir}/"

  # Sign the binaries we moved.
  local identity="${EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME:-$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}"
  if [[ -n "$identity" && "$identity" != "\"\"" ]]; then
    RunCommand codesign --force --verbose --sign "${identity}" -- "${xcode_frameworks_dir}/App.framework/App"
    RunCommand codesign --force --verbose --sign "${identity}" -- "${xcode_frameworks_dir}/Flutter.framework/Flutter"
  fi
}

# Main entry point.

# TODO(cbracken): improve error handling, then enable set -e

if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
  # Backwards-compatibility: if no args are provided, build.
  BuildApp
else
  case $1 in
    "build")
      BuildApp ;;
    "thin")
      ThinAppFrameworks ;;
    "embed")
      EmbedFlutterFrameworks ;;
  esac
fi
```

You can find this code [here (flutter repo)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/v1.12.13-hotfixes/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh).

To get to know about [read here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39507).

Me provided solution is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40146#issuecomment-567169130).