# New Flutter app build fails for simulator, permission denied

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

When I try to `flutter run` a newly created flutter app the build fails with the error below. The computer was used a year ago for Flutter development and I suspect there is some irregular config somewhere causing this error. I've been struggling with this for a few days now and any help would be much appreciated.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. `flutter create my_app`
2. `cd my_app`
3. `flutter run`

**Terminal output:**

```
app/Frameworks/App.framework/App: signed bundle with Mach-O universal
    (x86_64 arm64) [io.flutter.flutter.app]
    /Users/user/Desktop/projects/myApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.
    app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: replacing existing signature
    /Users/user/Desktop/projects/myApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.
    app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: Permission denied
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

**I have tried:**

- Uninstalling and re-installing Xcode
- Uninstalling and re-installing Flutter
- Running from Xcode
- Removing pods/podfiles and re-installing
- Restarting computer
- `flutter clean`
- Creating a new app
- Checking compliance with all required Flutter "[Get started](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos)" instructions
- Running from Xcode
- Switching workspace to Legacy Build System
- [Locking & unlocking login in Keychain Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code/53383349#53383349)
- Giving read/write permissions to the project folder and all enclosed items using Finder, and running `chmod +x` on files

**`flutter doctor -v` output:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.20.3 at /usr/local/Cellar/flutter/sdk
    • Framework revision 216dee60c0 (6 days ago), 2020-09-01 12:24:47 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.7)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.7, Build version 11E801a
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 (mobile) • 034B59B3-8929-4997-B7A1-53E32D065347 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-7 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

---

**UPDATE**: [I have opened an issue in the Flutter Github repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65378).

Comment: Check out this thread perhaps: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50568

Comment: @Kris Attempted that fix but it did not solve my problem. My error is different, specifically: `Permission denied` `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this issue and run the Flutter demo app on the iOS Simulator by taking the following steps:

1. `flutter version v1.11.0` (to downgrade to an earlier version of Flutter)
2. `flutter channel stable`
3. `flutter upgrade`
4. `flutter doctor`
5. `flutter create test_app`
6. `cd test_app`
7. `flutter run`

Comment: I does not work now with the newer versions

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091905/why-to-fix-frameworks-flutter-framework-permission-denied-while-building-ios) question, it seems like it's something to do with `xcode_backend.sh` file making some Flutter files read-only, check the question and [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40146) issue, might help you fix it, best of luck.

Comment: Tried this, but it did not fix my issue. (Comments under that issue mention the problem was resolved in a version of Flutter published in Dec 2019).